# Return Ajax Jquery response from web method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax Jquery for Curd Operation and i am validating my value from code behind in c#. if i find null or empty value then i want to return a string from web method as ajax failed/Error response. Please provide me solution for this.

your help will be appropriated.

Comment: you should tell us about your project. Is it an MVC project or WebForms. I suppose u r talking about webforms? Please specify that

Comment: Yes, i am using web form and thanks for replying me. @Argekumandan

Answer (score 0):

Here is the webmethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SomeMethod()
{ 
   return "OK";
}
```

that returns a string from http get method. And here is the jquery code

```
$.get( "SomeMethod", function( data ) {
  alert(data);
});
```